# How to change the image of Imageview on MouseClick

Tags: javafx, imageview, mouseevent

i am creating an application in javafx using scene builder. i have an imageview and i want to change the image when someone clicks on it. i have added a mouse event to the image view but it's not changing the image when i click on it. please find below the code for the same.

```
 public class HomeScreenController implements Initializable {
        @FXML
        public ImageView updateproject;
            public String updateprojectstyle="-fx-image:url(\"../../../../Images/update-enable.png\");";
        }
        @FXML
        private void updateProject(MouseEvent event) throws IOException
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
            updateproject.setStyle(updateprojectstyle);
        }
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
             //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }
```

### **Updated Question** (MCVE)

My FXML looks like:

```
 <VBox prefHeight="658.0" prefWidth="162.0" styleClass="sidepanel" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Pane maxHeight="138.0" maxWidth="162.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fx:id="addproject" fitHeight="60.0" fitWidth="66.0" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="39.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" styleClass="addproject-img" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane maxHeight="138.0" maxWidth="162.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fx:id="updateproject" fitHeight="57.0" fitWidth="84.0" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="32.0" onMouseClicked="#updateProject" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" styleClass="updateproject-img" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane layoutX="10.0" layoutY="148.0" maxHeight="138.0" maxWidth="162.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fx:id="deleteproject" fitHeight="59.0" fitWidth="80.0" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="32.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" styleClass="deleteproject-img" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
     </VBox>
```

My Controller looks like:

```
public class HomeScreenController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public ImageView updateproject;
     @FXML
    public ImageView addproject;
      @FXML
    public ImageView deleteproject;
     public String updateprojectstyle="-fx-image:url(\"../../../../Images/update-enable.png\");";
    public String addprojectstyle="-fx-image:url(\"../../../../Images/add-disable.png\");";
 @FXML
    private void updateProject(MouseEvent event) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("hello");
    updateproject.setStyle(updateprojectstyle);
     addproject.setStyle(addprojectstyle);
}
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
         //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

My css looks like:

```
.updateproject-img{
   -fx-image:url("../../../../Images/update-disable1.png");
}
.addproject-img{
     -fx-image:url("../../../../Images/add-active.png");
}
.deleteproject-img{
    -fx-image:url("../../../../Images/delete-disable1.png");
}
```

i want to disable the add project icon and enable the update project icon when the user clicks on update project image view. click event is firing but it's not loading the image.

Comment: Why are you use css for setting the image? Moreover, images on `ImageView` are set via `-fx-image:url(...)` and not via `-fx-background-image:url(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code with the css style on the ImageView.

Images on ImageView are set via `-fx-image:url(...)` and not via `-fx-background-image:url(...)`, as you have used in your code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ChangeImageViewImage extends Application {


    private static final String IMAGE1 = "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130120032553/dragonball/images/3/32/Chibi-Ichigo-bleach-anime-33253004-332-400.png";
    private static final String IMAGE2 = "https://40.media.tumblr.com/68f246eef26984be8a44e4367cfedd47/tumblr_n3lsszuyj41txcp2ko1_500.jpg";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitHeight(400);
        imageView.setFitWidth(300);
        imageView.setStyle("-fx-image: url(\""+ IMAGE1 + "\");");

        imageView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            imageView.setStyle("-fx-image: url(\""+ IMAGE2 + "\");");
        });

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have set an image to the image view in css file.. now on clicking the image view i just want to change the image.. actually the concept is when i load the page the image would be in inactive state, i have to activate the image(change the image) when i perform a click action.. as you suggested i just changed the -fx-background-image:url(...) to -fx-image:url(...) but now when i click on it the image is disappearing..

Comment: May be the application is not able to load the image. The problem with using css is that you do not see an exception if the url is incorrect, rather get a warning saying `WARNING: Error loading image:`. You should check out my complete example :)

Comment: i am not getting any warning/error in my console... i am using scene builder so i annotated my imageview id with @fxml in my controller...path of my image is also correct and even copy pasted the same  image to my controller and checked but it's not changing the image... i checked your example and changed few lines of code.. but it does not work :(

Comment: Then please create a MCVE and add it to your question.

Comment: Do the css from the fxml even apply? I don't find you loading them. Apart from it the way you are trying to change the image looks fine to me. I am overlooking some minor issue :P

Comment: yes... i am attaching it at the top of my fxml.. i just posted few snippets from my application where i am facing problem...